# jQuery Ajax call object property scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been working on a peske problem the last few days. I have created an object to handle a login script. The login script is processed by a PHP script witch echo's out a json object:

```
{'status' : true} // could also be false
```

The ajax request completes everytime and I can console.log() it. The problem is in the callback function. I have tried the following allowable parameters/functions from the docs:

```
complete
success
.done()
```

In the call back I am attempting to set an object property/variable depending on the return. It does not see this assignment until the second time the script is run. I am assuming it is because something runs before the other or a scope issue?

So to clarify:
Lets say the script runs and I get back true. I then want to set the status of the object property to that instead of false. I put a console.log() inside the callback and that works everytime however the main object wont see it unless i submit it twice.

Here is the code. Any and all help is appreciated:

```
var loginAuth = {
    form : $('form'),
    status : false,
    init : function() {
        loginAuth.ajaxCall();
    },
    ajaxCall : function(loginData) {
        // Get Post variables
        var loginData = {
            username : $('input[name=username]').val(),
            password : $('input[name=password]').val()
        };

        // Proccess the form 
        $.ajax(
            {
                url : "http://localhost/url-where-results-are",
                dataType : "json",
                type : "post",
                data : loginData,
            }).done(function(data) {
                if(typeof data != 'object')
                {
                    $.parseJSON(data);
                } else {
                    loginAuth.status = data;
                    console.log(loginAuth.status);
                }
            });
    }

} //// END loginAuth Object ////
```

Comment: try to change console.log(loginAuth.status) to console.log("mylog", loginAuth.status)

Comment: p.s. this is just to see that the result in the console is really your console log - and see that this really happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have some things wrong. You only want to `$.parseJson` if it is an object. Furthermore, you do not need to call that as jQuery handles the parsing for you.

```
if(typeof data != 'object')
            {
              $.parseJSON(data);
            } else {
              loginAuth.status = data;
              console.log(loginAuth.status);
            }
```

This would be correct:

```
if(typeof data == 'object') {
  alert(data.status);
  if(data.status == true) {
    loginAuth.status = true;
  } else {
    loginAuth.status = false;
  }
} else {
  console.log(data);

}
```